google locker doesnt fetch all the data from Postgresql database
I am using google locker, and I have a PostgreSQL database stored in Heroku.
I have a problem since the number of rows that are in the database is different to the number of rows showiing in google locker.
When I create the connection in google locker, using the formula:
SELECT * from Database;
gives different results than doing the same formula in the database (Google locker is missing like 300 rows.
My database only has 1600 records in total so should be pretty simlple. The database is a PostgreSQL hosted on Heroku. I have no filters, dates or repeated data.
It is the first and very basic step to create a report, making sure all the data will be available.
Any help on this? I am desperate.
Thank you all!
